How do I integrate four video feeds and their respective heatmaps in 2x2 grids
I have a flask project for people counting using YOLO. It is displaying four video feeds correctly in a 2x2 grid. The issue now is that I want to display their respective heatmaps also in a 2x2 grid such that I can visualize them perfectly. I am adding debug statements to check whether the videos passed are being processed correctly and they are being printed like "No person coordinates for heatmap 1", for instance.
Here is part of my code:
def generate_heatmap():

while True:
for i in range(4):  # Iterate through each heatmap
if heatmap_imgs[i] is not None:
print(f"Heatmap for feed {i} is available.")
ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', heatmap_imgs[i])
heatmap_frame = buffer.tobytes()
print("Yielding heatmap frame...")
yield (b'--frame\r\n'
b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + heatmap_frame + b'\r\n')
        else:
            print("No heatmap image available.")
    time.sleep(0.1)

Function to process each video frame
def process_frame(frame, model, tracker, class_list, person_coordinates):
results = model.predict(frame)  # Get predictions from the model
boxes = results[0].boxes.data  # Get bounding boxes (x1, y1, x2, y2)
detected_persons = []

for box in boxes:  # Loop through detected boxes
    x1, y1, x2, y2, conf, class_id = box  # Unpack the box
    if class_list[int(class_id)] == 'person':  # Check if detected class is 'person'
        detected_persons.append([int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)])  # Append bounding box as integer
        cx = (int(x1) + int(x2)) // 2  # Calculate center x
        cy = (int(y1) + int(y2)) // 2  # Calculate center y
        person_coordinates.append((cx, cy))  # Append coordinates

bbox_id = tracker.update(detected_persons)  # Update tracker with detected persons
for bbox in bbox_id:
    x3, y3, x4, y4, id = bbox
    cx = (x3 + x4) // 2
    cy = (y3 + y4) // 2
    cv2.circle(frame, (cx, cy), 4, (255, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x3, y3), (x4, y4), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cvzone.putTextRect(frame, f'{id}', (x3, y3), 1, 2)

return frame

def generate_frames(video_sources):
# Open video sources passed as an argument
caps = [cv2.VideoCapture(source) for source in video_sources]
if not all(cap.isOpened() for cap in caps):
print("Error: Could not open video file(s).")
exit()
while True:
    frames = []
    for cap in caps:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (510, 250))  # Resize to fit in grid
        processed_frame = process_frame(frame, model, tracker, class_list, person_coordinates)
        frames.append(processed_frame)

    if len(frames) < 4:
        break  # If we didn't get enough frames, exit the loop

    # Create a 2x2 grid for the frames
    top_row = cv2.hconcat(frames[:2])  # Concatenate the first two frames
    bottom_row = cv2.hconcat(frames[2:])  # Concatenate the last two frames
    composite_frame = cv2.vconcat([top_row, bottom_row])  # Concatenate top and bottom rows

    # Encode frame to JPEG format
    ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', composite_frame)
    frame = buffer.tobytes()

    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

